QEMU freezes during boot on riscv64, stuck after displaying startup progress
I am encountering an issue with QEMU when trying to emulate a riscv64 architecture. QEMU starts, but freezes after displaying the boot progress bar, and there is no further output. I'm attempting to simulate a riscv64 system and load the Linux kernel, but it seems to halt during the boot process. Below are the commands I used and the relevant output:
Command I ran:
qemu-system-riscv64 \
-nographic \
-machine virt \
-kernel $OUT/bbl \
-append 'root=/dev/vda ro console=ttyS0' \
-drive file=$OUT/riscv_disk,format=raw,id=hd0,if=none \
-device virtio-blk-device,drive=hd0

Output froze like:
qemu-system-riscv64 -D ~/qemulog.txt -nographic -smp 2 -machine virt -bios none -kernel $OUT/bbl -append 'root=/dev/vda ro console=ttyS0' -drive file=$OUT/riscv_disk,format=raw,id=hd0,if=none -device virtio-blk-device,drive=hd0
hart_filter_mask saw unknown hart type: status="okay", mmu_type="riscv,sv57"
hart_filter_mask saw unknown hart type: status="okay", mmu_type="riscv,sv57"

The output file here -D ~/qemulog.txt is empty, i have set the bbl and linux kernel following https://github.com/ppeetteerrs/gem5-RISC-V-FS-Linux
How can I diagnose and resolve this issue where QEMU freezes during boot?

I’ve tried using different qemu versions and alternate disk images, but the issue remains.
I’ve also tried adjusting the number of CPUs with the -smp option, but it doesn’t solve the problem.

